# Get previous 24 hours from specific date using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pull the last 24 hours from specific date.  In my table, i have a lot of data points but i only want to pull prior 24 hours from the selected ID.  Here is example

```
select ID, Name, FullDatetime from myTable where ID = 53
```

the result of this query will look like this:

```
ID   Name         FullDateime
53   John    2015-03-11 02:00:00.000
```

So i want to pull the last 24 hours prior to this date. Please help.  thanks

Comment: `FullDateTime - 1`?  `DATEADD(hour, -24, FullDatetime)` ? `DATEADD(day, -1, FulleDatetime)` ?

Comment: dateadd(day,-1,fulldatetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, to get the records that have a `FullDateTime` value within the last 24 hours of the `FullDateTimeValue` for `ID` 53, you can use a self join:

```
    select mt1.ID, mt1.Name, mt1.FullDateTime
    from myTable mt1
        inner join myTable mt2 
            on mt1.FullDateTime between DATEADD(hour, -24, mt2.FullDateTime) and mt2.FullDateTime 
                 and mt2.ID = 53
```

Since you mention you have a lot of data points, performance could be a concern. If we knew what indexes you had on the table, perhaps the query could be written to use them better. If you have an index on `FullDateTime`, the above query will use that (on `mt1`).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not totally clear on what you want, do you want records 24 hours old and younger or older?

Older:

```
select ID, Name, FullDatetime from myTable 
where ID = 53 
     and dateadd(day, 1, FullDatetime) < @myDate
```

Younger

```
select ID, Name, FullDatetime from myTable 
where ID = 53 
     and dateadd(day, 1, FullDatetime) > @myDate
```

Comment: what is @myDate?  i have to run this first in order to know what date to start from the data: select ID, Name, FullDatetime from myTable where ID = 53